# .htaccess with database

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I do this that mydomain.com/ -> mydomain.com/profile.php?username=

Now You can start search via url like domain.com/

My htaccess file is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=search&val=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I can understand in php file

```
$val = $_GET['val'];
if($c->userNameCheck($val))
{
    header("Location:".$url."/profile.php?username=".$val);
}
```

But I dont want to show profile.php

Comment: Why not `domain.tld/search/yoda` or `domain.tld/users/yoda`?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply replace the rule with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, since you won't be executing the `index.php` file, the `userNameCheck` method won't be called. I assume it does some sort of a check if the provided parameter is a valid username -- to make it run with the modified rule, you'd have to move that call to the `profile.php` file.